# Java Swing; Problems with Java GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds() returning 0

Tags: java, swing

It seems that the .getBounds() method of the GraphicsConfiguration class is not reporting the correct values.

```
   GraphicsDevice[] gdArr = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();

        int width = 0;
        for (GraphicsDevice gd : gdArr)
        {
            if (gd.getType() == gd.TYPE_RASTER_SCREEN)                                                
                System.out.println("Value is: " + gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getX());                
        }
```

I have two monitors: running 1920 * 1080 and 1280 * 1080.

I get the following values:

for .getX() I get:

```
Value = 1920
Value = 0
```

for .getY() I get:

```
Value = 0
Value = 0
```

I'm running on a Linux platform with Nvidia's Twinview.  Is this a bug outside of Swing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug.  The values are correct.

You are getting the bounds of each screen, and then you are getting the X and Y coordinates of each bound, which is the coordinate of the upper-left corner.  `GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds()` returns a `Rectangle` defining the screen boundaries. `Rectangle.getX()` and `Rectangle.getY()` return the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the rectangle.  `Rectangle.getWidth()` and `Rectangle.getHeight()` return the size.

You have two monitors.  Here are the boundaries of each monitor:

```
1: X = 0   , Y = 0, Width = 1920, Height = 1080
2: X = 1920, Y = 0, Width = 1280, Height = 1080
```

Comment: +1.  Rectangle implements toString, so try just `System.out.println(...getBounds());` to see the whole deal.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10/Java 8 the ratio of `text scaling factors` goes into coordinates of secondary screens.

E.g. Two screens, widths 1920 + 1600 with common border line, both text scaling 125%

`Bounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080]`

`Bounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=1920,y=174,width=1600,height=900]`

Now, when the text scaling of the second screen is changed to 100%, I get

`Bounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080]`

`Bounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=2400,y=218,width=2000,height=1125]` .

The bounds of the second screen appear scaled by 125%. This is to be considered,
e.g. when capturing all screens, which independent from text scaling will produce a section

`Bounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=1920,y=174,width=1600,height=900]`

for the secondary screen.

## EDIT

`GraphicDevice.getDisplayMode().getWidth()` delivers the text-scale-invariant value 1600 for the second screen and so the correcting factor for the rectangles reported by `GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds()`